# How to shield a HTML tag from CSS?

Tags: html, css

is there any way to isolate a HTML element from the CSS? I am trying to make a  and all it children from become "not visible" in a document.

The user is able to inform a css which is called on the document but I need to make sure that this  won't get lost, I mean, no display:none, visibility:hidden, text-indent:-10000px, left:-10000px, or any other of these tricks.

```
<div class="foo">
 <a href="#foo">link</a>
 <img src="" />
 <span>bar</span>
</div>
```

I could use a data:text/html;base64 iframe, but then the text won't be formatted.

Think about a disclaimer or a logomark. The user can include his own CSS (by informing the CSS URL) on my widget and I need to keep that disclaimer visible even the user specifies an display:none or text-indent on his CSS for that disclaimer element or any of it's children.

I am not trying to use no style, I just wanna know if there is any attribute to shield a <tag/>, something like "-moz-user-select: none;"

Comment: what you want to do has nothing to do with isolating html elements from css. when you give an element no styling don't means it is "not visible".

Comment: IF you HTML element is not referenced in your CSS document, it won't get styled. Your going about things backwards. Style the element you want to do something (You havent said) with a class.

Comment: Think about a disclaimer or a logomark. As I said, the user can include his own CSS (by informing the CSS URL) on my widget and I need to keep that disclaimer visible even the user specifies an display:none or text-indent on his CSS for that disclaimer element or it children.

I am not trying to use no style, I just wanna know if there is any attribute to shield a <tag/>, something like "-moz-user-select: none;"

Comment: Why voting this down and closing ? It is a perfectly good question. I was just today asked how to hide a "this version is freeware" image so the asker did not have to pay to hide the copyright.

Comment: Did one of the posts answer your question? If so, please accept the one that was the most correct/helpful. Thanks! (See [How do I ask questions here? in FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previous answers pointed out, there is no attribute to do that, and the `!important` approach won't work either, why? mainly because the users can use their own css, and if the user places `!important` in every style attribute, it will overwrite previous `!important` tagged attributes, here's an example:

`Site.css`
    .copyright { display: block !important; /* other styles here */ }

`Uploaded css`
    .copyright { display: none !important; /* ... */ }

The only way you may overcome it is reading the uploaded stylesheet and remove **every** `!important`, in that case you could use `!important` to avoid the style attribute to be overwritten.

> EDIT:
>   But you will have to actively declare every single attribute the user might use to *hide* elements.

Comment: The `!important` approach *will* work, because the user does not have access to the HTML, and therefore cannot change the inline `style` attribute. Also, due to the specificity of the inline `style` attribute combined with `!important`, the user cannot override *any* of the styles declared by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything that will work 100% of the time, but here's a solution that will work in most cases:

```
<div class="foo" style="background:#fff !important;color:#000 !important;position:relative !important;display:block !important;visibility:visible !important;opacity:1 !important;float:none !important;left:0 !important;top:0 !important;">
 <a href="#foo" style="background:#fff !important;color:#000 !important;position:relative !important;display:inline !important;visibility:visible !important;opacity:1 !important;float:none !important;left:0 !important;top:0 !important;">link</a>
 <img src="" style="background:#fff !important;color:#000 !important;position:relative !important;display:inline !important;visibility:visible !important;opacity:1 !important;float:none !important;left:0 !important;top:0 !important;" />
 <span style="background:#fff !important;color:#000 !important;position:relative !important;display:inline !important;visibility:visible !important;opacity:1 !important;float:none !important;left:0 !important;top:0 !important;">bar</span>
</div>
```

Basically, you want to specify `!important` for every style you don't want overridden in the `style` attribute. It's a huge pain if done manually, and like I said before, *can* be worked around by someone who's fluent with CSS.

***Note:** The styles provided are not an exhaustive list, just things I can think of off the top of my head.*

[About CSS Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity)

Comment: What in the world. I see what you're going for, by why wouldn't you just assign it to a class and apply the class to the elements? Also, why are you using so many `!important`s, you're already doing it as inline code, it has more weight to begin with. I can't imagine needing to use an `!important` on inline styles...

Comment: @MetalFrog because of CSS selector weight. That method can be overwritten. Inline important styles are the heaviest and almost impossible to overwrite. +1 bfrohs

Comment: Class can be overridden if not provided in the correct order. Inline styles cannot be overridden by external CSS.

Comment: Again, I can't imagine needing that much weight, nor can I imagine an instance in which I'd like to replicate that much code.

Comment: @MetalFrog The OP is specifically asking how he can make it as difficult as possible for a user of his widget to remove legal copy from it. This is a decent method if the user doesn't have access to the markup.

Comment: @BryanDowning If there's a will, there's a way.

Comment: @MetalFrog, aye, but this makes it a whole lot harder :) And, as the OP mentioned, the users in question aren't the most tech-savvy, so they won't be able to get around it as easily and you or I.

Comment: @MetalFrog No arguments here, the point is it makes it more difficult.

Comment: @MetalFrog, also, having the `!important` on inline styles is to override `!important` on external styles (which would normally override a normal inline style).

Comment: @bfrohs Yeah, my bad. I was just entirely off on what the request was and what your solution was doing. Brain fart.

Comment: @BryanDowning, that's it. The user don't access the markup. I was just  asking to know if there were any solution besides the _dirty_ inline way.  Thanks!

Comment: @Zanaca, nope, that's the only way, unless you want to put their content inside of an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no attribute to shield a tag.